Controlling CSS on Hover in Lighting Datable Inline Edit Mode
I have been able to dynamically change the background cell color in a Lighting Data Table using cellAttributes and a fieldname e.g.
    else if (attendeefields.fieldValue === 'Attended') {
        objrow[statusnametemp] = 'slds-theme_success slds-text-color_inverse';
    }


But because I am using slds-text-color_inverse, it goes awry when I hover over the cell - as you can see here:

Once I click the edit icon, and the custom datatype for the picklist appears, it looks ok - but I am wondering if there is a way to alter the css for the hover mode for a cell in a datatable? I haven't found anything that seems to offer a way to set that? As you can see, if I use black text if works correctly, but the inverse text is much easer to read, so would prefer to do that if can?

Same problem here, but as I'm attempting to customize a cell using a success or warning badge, it doesn't look good no matter which text color I use.
Hope a solution is posted here because I tried a couple of links and nothing worked.
